# Probability and combinations question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Find the probability that a poker hand of 5 cards from a standard deck will contain exactly 2 face cards (i.e. J,Q,K) (event A), given that it contains exactly 1 cards smaller than 8 (i.e. 2,...,7)(event B)”?

1. What is the size of the union of Event A and Event B?
2. What is the size of set of Event B?
3. What is the conditional probability P(A|B)?

If someone can explain to me how to get these, that would be amazing!

Comment: Seems like a homework question!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and what's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

There are various sample spaces we could use. The number of outcomes in our events depends on the choice of sample space.

However, there is a "natural" sample space, the set of $5$-card hands, and we will work with that.

It is odd that Question 1 is first, since the natural way to solve it involves solving, in particular, Question 2.

We count the number of $5$-card hands that have exactly $1$ card below $8$. There are $24$ such cards. We must choose $1$ of these, and $4$ cards from the remaining $28$. This can be done in $\binom{24}{1}\binom{28}{4}$ ways. That is the answer to Question 2.

Now we count the number of outcomes in event $A$. The $2$ face cards can be chosen in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways, and for each choice the $3$ non-face cards can be chosen in $\binom{40}{3}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{12}{2}\binom{40}{3}$.

To find the number of events in $A\cup B$, the formula $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ is handy. We have almost all the pieces, only need $|A\cap B|$.

So we want to count the hands that have exactly $2$ face cards, exactly $1$ card below $8$, and $2$ others. There are $\binom{12}{2}\binom{24}{1}\binom{16}{2}$ of these.

Now to answer Question 1, put the various pieces together.

For Question 3, we want $\Pr(A|B)$. By the usual definition of conditional probability, we have $\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

The proability of $A\cap B$ is obtained by dividing the number of outcomes in $A\cap B$ by $\binom{52}{5}$. The probability of $B$ is obtained in a similar way. Divide.

There is cancellation, and our answer is $\frac{|A\cap B|}{|B|}$. The two numbers required to finish things have been computed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Event A - there are 3 face cards, 4 kinds of each card, totally 12. There are 52 cards in a deck so the probability to get 2 face cards are $\frac{12}{52}\frac{11}{51}$.

Event B - I understood that you need the prob. to get exactly 1 card smaller than 8. There are 6 X 4 such cards (assuming that an ace is bigger than 8), so the prob. to get exactly 1 such card is $\frac{24}{52}\frac{28}{51}\frac{27}{50}\frac{26}{49}\frac{25}{48}$, meaning choose one of the 24 and then any card other than the remaining 23 that are smaller than 8.

Now that you have P(A) and P(B), can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I approached this using combinatorics. I may have missed something, but I first looked at the situation of drawing exactly two face cards in a five card hand with a 52 card deck and no prior information.

The number of ways to choose 5 cards from a 52 card deck is: $\binom{52}{5}$

The number of ways to choose 2 face cards is: $\binom{12}{2}$

But we must also include the number of ways of choosing 3 non-face cards: $\binom{40}{3}$

Therefore we arrive at: P = $\frac{\binom{12}{2}\binom{40}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}$=0.25

Now we need to include the given information. We can approach this by assuming that we are now starting off with 1 card in our hand, drawing from a deck of 51 with 1 less non-face card.

Therefore: P = $\frac{\binom{12}{2}\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{51}{4}}$=0.19